# How to splits the line at x characters or less, and only at a space (" ")?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating program which splits the line at x characters and only at a space (" ").

Input paragraph:

> There was no possibility of taking a walk that day. We had been wandering, indeed, in the leafless shrubbery an hour in the morning; but since dinner (Mrs. Reed, when there was no company, dined early) the cold winter wind had brought with it clouds so sombre, and a rain so

Input split characters: 30

Now I am getting output like this:

```
var textArray = ["There was no possibility of ta","king a walk that day. We had b","een wandering, indeed, in the ","leafless shrubbery an hour in ","the morning; but since dinner ","(Mrs. Reed, when there was no ","company, dined early) the cold"," winter wind had brought with ","it clouds so sombre, and a rai","n so "]`
```

But I want only splits at the space (). It splits at the last space before the number of characters specified.

I want output like this:

```
var textArray = ["There was no possibility of", "taking a walk that day. We", "had been wandering, indeed, in", "the leafless shrubbery an hour", "in the morning; but since", "dinner (Mrs. Reed, when there", "was no company, dined early)", "the cold winter wind had", "brought with it clouds so", "sombre, and a rain so", "penetrating, that further", "out-door exercise was now out", "of the question."]`
```

I tried this code :

```
function textToArray() {
       var str = document.getElementById('stringg').value;
       var strArr = [];
       var count = parseInt(document.getElementById('numberOfWords').value, 10) || 1;

       for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i = i + count) {
            var j = i + count;
            strArr.push(str.substring(i,j));
       }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Do you have some code to show us?

Comment: Why don’t you just split it by words? 30 characters = 5 or 6 words.  Split the whole string by spaces and get every 5 indices.

Comment: kindly check my update question @Jordumus

Comment: Isn't it funny how adding just a little bit of code, all of a sudden gives you 3 answers? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use array.reduce:

```js
var str = "There was no possibility of taking a walk that day. We had been wandering, indeed, in the leafless shrubbery an hour in the morning; but since dinner (Mrs. Reed, when there was no company, dined early) the cold winter wind had brought with it clouds so sombre, and a rain so";
str = str.split(' ').reduce((m, o) => {
    var last = m[m.length - 1];
    if (last && last.length + o.length < 30) {
        m[m.length - 1] = `${last} ${o}`;
    } else {
        m.push(o);
    }
    return m;
}, []);
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this approach (*comments inline*)

```js
var input = "There was no possibility of taking a walk that day. We had been wandering, indeed, in the leafless shrubbery an hour in the morning; but since dinner (Mrs. Reed, when there was no company, dined early) the cold winter wind had brought with it clouds so sombre, and a rain so";

function splitter(input, maxChars) {
  var output = [];
  output.push( input.split(" ").reduce(function(a, b) {
    if (a.length + b.length < maxChars) {
      a += " " + b; //if comnined length is still not execeeding add it a
    } else {
      output.push(a); //if combined less is exceeding the maxchars then push the last sentence to output
      a = b;
    }
    return a;
  })); //push the residue to output
  return output;
}

console.log( splitter( input, 30 ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd loop over the text, determine of the current char is a valid separator and if not, go looking for the nearest space.

```js
const
  input = 'There was no possibility of taking a walk that day. We had been wandering, indeed, in the leafless shrubbery an hour in the morning; but since dinner (Mrs. Reed, when there was no company, dined early) the cold winter wind had brought with it clouds so sombre, and a rain so';
  
function splitText(text, maxLength = 30) {
  const 
    result = [];

  // Keep looping till the input string is empty.
  while (text !== '') {
    // Initialize endIndex to the specified max length for the substring.
    let 
      endIndex;
      
    // A: If the max length is more than the remaining text length, adjust the 
    //    end index so it coincides with the remaining text length.
    // B: Else check if the character at the max length is NOT a space, in this 
    //    case go looking to a space as close to the max length as possible.
    if (maxLength > text.length) {  // [A]
      endIndex = text.length;
    } else if (text.substring(maxLength, 1) !== ' ') { // [B}
      endIndex = text.lastIndexOf(' ', maxLength);
    } else {
      endIndex = maxLength;
    }
    // Take the string with the determined length and place it in the result array.
    result.push(text.substring(0, endIndex));
    // Adjust the input string, remove the part that was just pushed into the result.
    text = text.substr(endIndex).trim();
  }

  return result;
}


console.log(splitText(input));
```

Comment: I was curious about the performance of the various solutions, so I made a JSPerf to test them. I removed the comments from my code so that doesn't take up unneeded parsing time. See here for the benchmark: https://jsperf.com/splitbywholewords/1

Answer (score 0):

You could take the last element of the array and check if the lenght is smaller/equa than expacted, then concat the temporary string to the result set, otherwise concat the last string and the actual item to the result set.

```js
var string = "There was no possibility of taking a walk that day. We had been wandering, indeed, in the leafless shrubbery an hour in the morning; but since dinner (Mrs. Reed, when there was no company, dined early) the cold winter wind had brought with it clouds so sombre, and a rain so";

string = string.split(' ').reduce(function (r, a) {
    var last = r.pop() || '',
        temp = last + (last && ' ') + a;
    return r.concat(temp.length <= 30 ? temp : [last, a]);
}, []);

console.log(string);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With ES6, you could take a recursive approach with rest operator and using the first parameter for adding the string until it gets the wanted length, then return that part.

```js
function join(a, b, ...rest) {
    if (!b) {
        return [a];
    }
    return a.length + b.length < 30
        ? join(a + ' ' + b, ...rest)
        : [a, ...join(b, ...rest)];
}

var string = "There was no possibility of taking a walk that day. We had been wandering, indeed, in the leafless shrubbery an hour in the morning; but since dinner (Mrs. Reed, when there was no company, dined early) the cold winter wind had brought with it clouds so sombre, and a rain so";

console.log(join(...string.split(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```